# How to configure Kodi, running on ubuntu, for fullscreen mode

Tags: xorg, xbmc, kodi, xinit

I have an Ubuntu box which displays [`kodi`](https://kodi.tv/) fullscreen on my TV. It is started in `/etc/rc.local` via

```
/usr/bin/xinit /usr/bin/kodi
```

Today a toddler got hold of the keyboard for a split second and managed, though a keyboard combination, to switch the screen so that the `kodi` window now takes about 1/6th of the screen. It is in the upper-left corner, the rest of the screen is blank and when moving the mouse, the cursor changes from an arrow (while above the small screen) to a cross while outside.

It looks like the case where one starts `xinit` with just an `xterm` (which also takes that part of the screen).

(wild guesses follow) It may be that the keyboard combination instructed `kodi` to use a smaller resolution, or `xinit`to use a larger one (and thus pushing `kodi` into a smaller screen).

I rebooted the computer but it now boots into this configuration as well (so - wild guesses again - it may be that the keyboard combination switched a permanent parameter, but it was a split second so it could not have been much more than `Ctrl-M-Shift-Left Arrow-P`)

Since the conversational possibilities with the baby are tiny I would appreciate any pointer on where to look for a solution.

Comment: Could have been F11.

Comment: To toggle between full screen and windowed mode press the backslash-key "\"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Kodi goto

> **System → Settings → System → Video output**

Change the option "Display mode" from "Windowed" to "Full screen"

To toggle between "Windowed" and "Full screen" mode you also can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>`\`</kbd> (the backslash key). Look at [Keyboard controls (Kodi wiki)](http://kodi.wiki/view/Keyboard_controls) for more Kodi keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

The key which toggled the modes was `*`.

I believe that it may be a shortcut for the other actions described in @cmks' answer (which did not work for me but may for others - fullscreen mode was already enabled)